# First steps in Entity Framework, is there a link with hibernate?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, hibernate, entity-framework

In the past, I've used Hibernate in a Delphi environment: I had an XML file and I retrieved an XSD schema out of it.
Next to that, I have done some updates with my Delphi environment, in order to make it ready for Hibernate purposes (I don't remember exactly which updates). Then I used that additional "plugin" for creating Delphi classes, one for every entry in my XSD schema, in order for the Delphi classes' structure to correspond with the XSD schema.

Now I'm having my first steps in Entity Framework in C#, and I expect a similar behaviour:

- I have a MSSQL (SQL Server) database.
- I launch some application (commandline or under Visual Studio), to which I feed my MSSQL (SQL Server) DB, and automatically, the application generates a whole bunch of `*.cs` files, each of them containing the structure of the tables in my SQL Server database.
- From there, I can continue like described in [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/).

I believe that this is not at all the way to work, and that my experience with Hibernate is blurring my vision. Can somebody tell me how I can make my list of `*.cs` files, based on my SQL Server database, in order to obtain an Entity Framework model?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's a tool called `xsd.exe` that creates cs files from xsd files. But I have never used the resulting files with a database, so I don't know those steps.

Comment: Your vision is blurred, its seems the terminology you are looking for is called EF *database first* https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx

Comment: @TheGeneral: I've indeed already heard of the term *database first*. In my opinion, it means that you first create your DB, and you derive your source code (`*.cs` files in my case) later. So my question becomes, is there a tool for automatically generating "Entity Framework compatible" `*.cs` files out of an SQL server database?

Comment: Indeed there is, follow the link

Comment: @TheGeneral: sorry, I've written my last comment before you inserted the hyperlink.

Comment: It might take a while to get your head around where you do these commands and the whole technology flow. YouTube might be a good resource, or someone might post a detailed answer for you... good luck

Comment: @TheGeneral: unfortunately I can't use the command `scaffold-...`: I'm working with .Net framework v4.6.1, I have the packages `EntityFramework.6.4.4\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll` and `EntityFramework.6.4.4\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll` but apparently, `scaffold-...` command requires `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` which, in its turn, requires `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.5.0.10`, which I can't install because of .Net Framework version issues. Is there a "scaffold-..." command for my (older) version of Entity Framework?

Comment: For EF 6 , try following along here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/workflows/database-first